# Modifying Labels and Objects in Forms from Classes (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, class, label, progress-bar, invoke

I have a class that gets the internet time and displays it in a text box. This is that class name `InternetTimeGet`

I have added a "progress meter" in that class that will show how far through the list of IPs the program is. Right now the Debug Console is displaying these IPs and updates fine as is shown here: [IPs and Progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mvlg5.png)

Everything is already multithreaded and nothing is hanging my UI

However, I'm having trouble getting the program to display the progress on a label named `ProgLbl` in my main form named `MainForm`. Here is the code of my `InternetTimeGet` class:

```
Public Class InternetTimeGet

    'Irrelevant variables omitted...

    'Used to update progress
    Public Shared IPCount As Integer
    Public Shared ProgDivision As Single
    Public Shared ProgBar As Single
    Public Shared FullBar As Integer = 100   

    IPCount = My.Settings.ServerIPList.Count
    ProgDivision = FullBar / IPCount

    For Each IP As String In ServArray
        Try
            'Shows each IP and the Percentage completion in Debug console
            Debug.WriteLine(IP, "IP Addresses")
            ProgBar = ProgBar + ProgDivision
            Debug.WriteLine(Math.Round(ProgBar, 1) & "%", "Progress")

            MainForm.ProgLbl.Text = "Progress: " & Math.Round(ProgBar, 1) & "%"

            If My.Computer.Network.Ping(IP) Then
                LastHost = IP
                Result = GetNISTTime(IP)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Return "Sync Error 0x01"
            MsgBox("There was a sync error while retrieving the updated internet time. Please try again.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Sync Error 0x01")
            Debug.WriteLine("There was a sync error while retrieving the updated internet time. Please try again.", "Sync Error 0x01")
        End Try
    Next
```

The Debug console shows *each IP and the percentage of completion* fine and does not not show intermediate updates or hang the UI, but the label `ProgLbl` in my main form `MainForm` does not show these updates at all and just remains saying "Progress: ". Once again *my main form* `MainForm`'s *UI **DOES NOT** hang.*

The problem is updating the label, `ProgLbl`, in my main form, `MainForm`, from the `InternetTimeGet` class shown above. That's what I'd appreciate help with.

I have been looking for an answer and tried several things but finally gave up and decided to ask those who know better.

Thank you for your help

Comment: I suppose that MainForm is the class name not the instance actually displayed of your main form, right?

Comment: Where is that code located?  Do you see the last msg (presumably "100%")? It might be working but you just dont see any of the intermediate updates.  Then again it may be related to default form instances (if `MainForm` is the class name and not the instance name).

Comment: First line... "I have a class that gets the internet time and displays it in a text box" and this code is obviously pulling internet time. This is the code from that class. `MainForm` is the main form of the project. In `MainForm` there is a Label called ProgLbl. I'm trying to get this class to send progress updates to that label. As it stands right now, the IPs and progress updates are displaying fine in the Debug console, and no, they are not hanging the UI as I've multithreaded everything already

Comment: I have updated the original post to be more clear and obvious about what I need help with. Thank you

Comment: `MainForm` sounds like it is the class name of the form.  That means you are using default form instances which is likely the problem. Create or acquire the form *instance* then, rather than fiddling with the controls in some other class, create a method to allow other actors to pass data to it.  The form can update the control(s) itself.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is not clear where your code is implemented but if you want to make some operation (such as getting time and going through a list of IPs), as a general rule, you'll want to avoid to do it in the main thread to avoid freezing the UI.

The background worker is perfect for that kind of purpose, as it will allow you to run code Async while reporting progress so you can update your main form.

Here is a simple example using a background worker 
that you will have to rework to fit your need.

```
Private WithEvents _GetTimeWorker As BackgroundWorker
```

Somewhere in your form, you need to initialize your worker and set the WorkerReportProgress to true. You can then start the worker when you need.

```
Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    _GetTimeWorker = New BackgroundWorker With {.WorkerReportsProgress = True}
    _GetTimeWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub
```

DoWork is actually the async method that you put your logic in so it does not block the UI. When you want to update the progress bar, you call ReportProgress on your background worker.

```
Private Sub _GetTimeWorker_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles _GetTimeWorker.DoWork
    Dim watch As New Stopwatch
    watch.Start()

    'Just simulating some work. 
    While watch.ElapsedMilliseconds < 10000
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
        _GetTimeWorker.ReportProgress(CInt(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 10000 * 100))
    End While
End Sub
```

The progress bar value is updated from the progress changed function.

```
Private Sub _GetTimeWorker_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles _GetTimeWorker.ProgressChanged
    'There we change the progress bar value
    prog1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
End Sub
```

Comment: I have updated the thread to be more obvious about what I'm looking for help with. I don't need help with threading or hanging UIs as I've already multithreaded this program thoroughly. Nothing hangs. So thank you anyways, but if you could re-read the OP and re-answer accordingly I'd appreciate that

Comment: This is a great solution and well written. I love how BackgroundWorker simplifies all of this, but I still  believe creating delegates and writing methods to check if they need to be invoked is better solution. Mainly because you can run any method async at any time. I wrote an example of that as an answer to another question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37330987/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-need-to-use-and-update-controls-on-ui-thread/37335768#37335768